# Negative Hessian matrix in R optim

Tags: r, optimization, kalman-filter

I used the `optim()` function in R to find the min log likelihood, however the diagonal elements of the inverse of Hessian matrix turned out to be negative.

```
> round(diag(solve(KFopt$hessian)),2)
[1]    0.00   -0.08   -0.03    0.00   -0.47   -0.18 -167.32
```

Does that mean the optimization is wrong? So what should I do if I want to extract standard deviation of each estimates?

Comment: Typically, you want to maximize the log likelihood (which is a concave function) rather than minimizing it.

Comment: I already coded the function as negative log likelihood, then I put optim(psi,fn = function,...) to minimize (negative log likelihood), I think it should be correct..

Comment: Have you tried to change your initial values when applying `optim`?

Comment: I did, and sometimes it did work. But I don't think it is robust enough... Occasionally it works for a while but no longer works for same set of initial values..

Comment: I think it is sometimes just about luck to get it run...

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68080/basic-question-about-fisher-information-matrix-and-relationship-to-hessian-and-s/68095#68095 this post has helped me to understand the relationship between the hessian and fisher to find the std. error